# Sending POST json from Android and receiving on Django

Tags: android, django, post

I am trying to get an android app to interact with a server in Django.
The app is trying to POST "json" data to Django. However, I am unable to receive the object on the Django end.
The value of `request.POST` is `<QueryDict: {}>` although the data sent isn't blank. Following is the code snippet for POST request from android.

```
public static String POST(String url,JSONObject obj){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try{            
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = obj.toString();
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute((HttpUriRequest)httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        if(inputStream!=null){
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }else{
            result = "Did not work!";
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Earlier, I was getting CSRF error and handled it this way (I haven't worked with Django enough to know if this is correct way to handle CSRF error)

```
@csrf_exempt
def search(request):  
  logger.debug(request.POST)
  """Code for JSON object processing"""
```

Any help with rectifying the problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I'm not very fluent in java but it seems to me that your request is well formed.

I think the issue is that you are sending the data as a json string instead of as if it was a raw form. When you do it this way, the data is not displayed in `request.POST` but in `request.body` as what it is: a json string, not form-like data.

So I think you have to take one of these ways:

1. send the data from the Android app as a form (not json-like). This way you'll see it in `request.POST` or
2. translate `request.body` into a `dict` and work with it instead of `request.POST`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Indeed it helped. The json object was there in request.body. Thanks a lot.